# Getting pictures from an ftp server(locally) to display on website

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, webforms

I got my pictures on an ftp server, on my network, which i want to display on my website.

How can that be done?

Earlier i used `("/Boats/{BoatId}/{ImageId} + "." + {ImageExtension")` but now i have my pictures on `\\ftplocation\files\boatcompany\boats\`

I tried the following: (Works with the url above).

```
ImageUrl='<%# String.Format(@"\\ftp\files\boatcompany\boats\{0}\thumbnails\{1}.{2}", Eval("BoatId"), Eval("Image.ImageId"), Eval("Image.Extension")) %>' />
```

Comment: When you say "on my website" is this an internet facing website, or something that only you (on your network) will ever see/use? If it's internet facing you're going to have problems with UNC paths such as \\foo\bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Max's answer I wanted to add a third solution that works with both private and public ftp servers (and anything else really).

What you need to do is use your application as a proxy for the ftp.

- Add a page, f.ex. "getimage.aspx" which accept arguments, f.ex. id's of the image
- From the page, when called, response with header setting (mime-type etc.) (hold)
- Connect to ftp server, log in if needed and stream the file requested.
- Forward the content of that stream to your page's stream (response stream) and close.

Then you can do this (line breaks to make it more readable):

```
ImageUrl = '<%# 
    String.Format(@"/getimage.aspx?boatid={0}&imageid={1}&extension={2}", 
                  Eval("BoatId"), 
                  Eval("Image.ImageId"), 
                  Eval("Image.Extension")) %>'
```

For FTP you can use the built-in capabilities in .net or use a third-party extension such as [Rebex-FTP](http://www.rebex.net/ftp-ssl.net/) which makes streaming files from ftp a walk in the park.

Using a page to retrieve pictures this way makes it capable of obtaining images from various sources, not just ftp, at the same time keeping it transparent for the user.

Comment: I'd say this is the preferred method.  Max's is good, but usually  files aren't supposed to be directly accessible.

Comment: That's an universal method which will always work. But you have to write code, and new code can always introduce new bugs. Also, if you want to set cache rules, I would prefer to do it rather from IIS than in code. So, if files can be accessible locally by the IIS server, I would go with Virtual Folder solution, because it takes 1 minute to setup, it's reliable and maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

Because of security issues browsers will never load any resources (including images) from local storage. So, URLs like `\\server\myfile.jpg` or `file:///server/myfile.jpg` will never be loaded from an Internet web site. That's why your code doesn't work.

You have two options:

1 . If you ftplocation is a real FTP server and it can be accessed from the outer world with a real FTP URL, you can use this code:

```
ImageUrl='<%# String.Format(@"ftp://ftp.server.com/files/boatcompany/boats/{0}/thumbnails/{1}.{2}", Eval("BoatId"), Eval("Image.ImageId"), Eval("Image.Extension")) %>
```

2 . You can create a virtual subfolder in IIS inside your web project, call it `Boats` and point that virtual folder to `\\ftplocation\files\boatcompany\` folder. Then in your code use just this (pretty much the same code as you used before you've got the FTP):

```
ImageUrl='<%# String.Format(@"/Boats/{0}/thumbnails/{1}.{2}", Eval("BoatId"), Eval("Image.ImageId"), Eval("Image.Extension")) %>
```